# Does DB2 offer an advisory lock feature like postgres

Tags: db2, locking, db2-luw

In Postgres, the [Advisory Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) feature provides for arbitrary application-defined locks that have application-defined meanings. These locks are not related to any schemas/tables/rows as such and are very helpful.

I am looking for a similar lock feature in IBM DB2. I could not find any equivalents for DB2 when checking online resources. Does DB2 offer something like these Advisory Locks?

Comment: I believe the answer is NO.  But much depends on your true requirement (i.e. what problem you seek to solve).

Answer (score 0):

There is an Oracle compatibility module DBMS_LOCK, developed by IBM, though unsupported. You can use it as is or review its source and develop your own solution.

The source code for the set of modules, including DBMS_LOCK, can be [downloaded from developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=636bec0f-9dee-4d2a-b1e1-fa52db9b765d).